# Highcharts Gauge - how to read input from file?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I currently just started on JS and needed highcharts for a project, so far so good, but I do have a very newbie question:
I have some task doing a cron job and outputing a value range: 10-90 to a file. How can I load the value into the gauge?

Here is the code I adapted (ranges, look and feel dont matter), i only could make a static value  **53.8** :

```
 $(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'gauge',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Speedometer'
        },

        pane: {
            startAngle: -150,
            endAngle: 150,
            background: [{
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#FFF'],
                        [1, '#333']
                    ]
                },
                borderWidth: 0,
                outerRadius: '109%'
            }, {
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                    stops: [
                        [0, '#333'],
                        [1, '#FFF']
                    ]
                },
                borderWidth: 1,
                outerRadius: '107%'
            }, {
                // default background
            }, {
                backgroundColor: '#DDD',
                borderWidth: 0,
                outerRadius: '105%',
                innerRadius: '103%'
            }]
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 200,

            minorTickInterval: 'auto',
            minorTickWidth: 1,
            minorTickLength: 10,
            minorTickPosition: 'inside',
            minorTickColor: '#666',

            tickPixelInterval: 30,
            tickWidth: 2,
            tickPosition: 'inside',
            tickLength: 10,
            tickColor: '#666',
            labels: {
                step: 2,
                rotation: 'auto'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'km/h'
            },
            plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 120,
                color: '#55BF3B' // green
            }, {
                from: 120,
                to: 160,
                color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
            }, {
                from: 160,
                to: 200,
                color: '#DF5353' // red
            }]        
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Speed',
            data: [80],
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' km/h'
            }
        }]

    }
);
    $('#container').highcharts().series[0].points[0].update(50.8)
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/H8uGk/ , can you guys give me a tip how to read the content of a file? (a number in this case)

Is there any way to do it in javascript? It doesn't need to be dynamic , and i was avoiding using php.

Thank you,

Comment: You can prepare i.e script in php which returns JSON, then in Highcharts you can load by $.getJSON();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to just copy/paste it into your js file, which I'm assuming isn't good enough because you want it to be dynamic.

If you need it to be dynamic, you can't do this in javascript, because the javascript runs on the client (ie the web browser), but it needs to read from the server (ie the original machine).  So, you have to create an "endpoint" to read the file, check out something simple in php like this:

```
<?php
// > PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./gauge_data.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
?>
```